# Find Law of X of random variabel

Tags: probability

I am studying probability which heavily relies and Measure Theory 
I  still find trouble grasping certain concepts for example
I need to solve  this task:

Consider the probability space $(\mathbb{R}, \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}), \mathbb{P})$, where $\mathbb{P}$ is

$\mathbb{P}=0.1 \delta_{-2}+0.7 \delta_{1}+0.2 \delta_{10}$.

If $X(\omega)=2 \omega^{3} I_{(-\infty, 3]}(\omega)$, then the law of $X$ is:

My answer $\mathbb{P}_{X}=0.1 \delta_{-16}+0.7 \delta_{2}+0.2 \delta_{2000}$

Is that correct?

Comment: I think you've computed the law of $2 \omega^3$; you forgot to consider the indicator $I_{(-\infty, 3](\omega)$.

Comment: I  think you are right angryavian so I assume answer is $\mathbb{P}_{X}=0.1 \delta_{-16}+0.7 \delta_{2}+0.2 \delta_{0}$

Comment: Perfect, you found the law of $X$.